# Не запускается .jar файл с JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

В Eclipse все компилируется, а вот когда я запаковал .jar файл, он вообще не открывается.

Comment: Вы бы написали, что писали в консоли, и что она выводила. Попробуйте написать что-то вроде этого: `java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --enable-preview -jar MyProgram.jar`. Подставьте свой путь к javafx, своё название джарника и добавьте нужные модули.

Comment: можете конкретнее объяснить куда вписать это: java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --enable-preview -jar MyProgram.jar

Comment: В консоль, перейдя в консоли в директорию, в которой лежит джарник.

Comment: `C:\Users\Альфа>java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --enable-preview -jar MineLaunch2.jar
Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: это мне написало в консоле

Comment: Какая у вас версия джавы?

Comment: jre 8 а именно java хз

Comment: Ну тогда я придерживаюсь ответа `Perfect Voyage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустите через bat (Консоль)
И узнайте вашу ошибку.
Как сделать :
Создайте файл с раширением .bat , там где лежит ваш джарник.
В нем напишите java -jar имя_вашего_файла.jar.
Пробелов в имени быть не должно.

Comment: эм, я запустил вашу команду в командой строке, и запустил сам jar файл, и он запустился XD, как такое может быть? и ошибок не вылетело

Comment: нет, jar сам запустился но через кмд, а если по нему клацать, то хер он запустится

Comment: У вас приложение имеет GUI хоть ? )

Comment: конечно, у меня оно не через консоль работает как бы, поэтому и вопрос связанный с jvafx, была бы консоль я бы в тегах javafx не указывал

Comment: Тогда это действительно странно...)

Comment: ааа, почему у меня херня какая-то всегда с П.О XD , то андроид студио устновить не могу, тоже чего-то не хватает, и я не могу найти этого, ну ладно, спасибо на этом, оно теперь через консоль хотя бы запускается